# Access to the Security services in Sulu Frontend: Hashing a Users password

Tags: symfony, sulu

I'm trying to make a user registration for the Sulu CMF frontend.
I want to hash the passwords. But for any reason i can't get the Service.

```
You have requested a non-existent service "security.encoder_factory".
```

Or

```
You have requested a non-existent service "security.password_encoder"
```

If i ask for

```
app/console container:debug | grep encode
```

Both services are there

```
$ app/console container:debug | grep encode                    
263: security.encoder_factory                                                      Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\EncoderFactory                                     
266: security.password_encoder                                                     Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoder
```

Do you have any tip for me?
My Controller is aware of the Container and my code is the following:

```
$this->container->get('security.password_encoder')
```

Heres some output from conainer:debug

```
$ app/console container:debug security.password_encoder
[container] Information for service security.password_encoder
Service Id       security.password_encoder
Class            Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoder
Tags             -
Scope            container
Public           yes
Synthetic        no
Lazy             no
Synchronized     no
Abstract         no


$ app/console container:debug security.encoder_factory 
[container] Information for service security.encoder_factory
Service Id       security.encoder_factory
Class            Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\EncoderFactory
Tags             -
Scope            container
Public           yes
Synthetic        no
Lazy             no
Synchronized     no
Abstract         no
```

My currently installed version of symfony is v2.6.12

the command provided by sulu makes use of this method. It works in both environments, dev and prod.

```
/**
 * Encodes the given password, for the given password, with he given salt and returns the result.
 *
 * @param $user
 * @param $password
 * @param $salt
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
private function encodePassword($user, $password, $salt)
{
    /** @var PasswordEncoderInterface $encoder */
    $encoder = $this->getContainer()->get('security.encoder_factory')->getEncoder($user);

    return $encoder->encodePassword($password, $salt);
}
```

Comment: I'm calling from a controller. There i which extends Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller (which extends ContainerAware).

Comment: Which Symfony version do you use? And can you please show the output of `php app/console container:debug security.password_encoder` and `php app/console container:debug security.encoder_factory`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added more details above.

Comment: Is the output different when also using the `--env=prod` option?

Comment: [LogicException]                                                        
  Debug information about the container is only available in debug mode.

How can i check if I'm in debug mode?

Comment: It may be easier to just create a simple command that makes use of one of these services and then execute it in both the `dev` and the `prod` environment. Can you do that to ensure that your issue is not related to the environment?

Comment: app/console sulu:security:user:create --env=dev and app/console sulu:security:user:create --env=prod bot work as expected

I added the method used to generate the password in my question above.

Comment: Are you sure that the CLI and web front controllers actually share the same kernel then?

Comment: You're right. Sulu CMF has an extra console app called app/console webconsole which uses a different Kernel :-)

Comment: So now the service is not available and I know why :-)
Thats a big step in the right direction. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is a useful Question with good Answers, but the title is not that helpful - it's not really about hashing a password, it's about gaining access to the Security services in Sulu.  Any chance you could change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As xabbuh has already pointed out in the comments, we have two different kernels in Sulu. If you use the `app/webconsole` command, you are using the Kernel for the Website.

In the standard installation we don't include the `SecurityBundle`, because it adds some overhead, and is not necessary for simple websites. However, if you are building a more complicated application, you might also want to secure your website. In this case you can simply add a new instance of `Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle` to the `$bundles` array in `app/WebsiteKernel`. Afterwards there will also be the service available you have been asking for.

Answer (score 1):

Sulu CMF has an extra console app called app/console webconsole which uses a different Kernel :-)

The service i searched for is not existent there.
Instead i was able to use

```
$userManager = $this->container->get('sulu_security.user_manager');
```

Comment: That's a possible solution, depending on what you want to do. Will add another answer to achieve what you have actually asked for.

Comment: Thanks for the answer to you (all). A already accomplished my task now. My problem was that i didn't see that SULU has different Kernels :-)